# How to get full access to windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I want a (simple) way to get full access to ALL files on my pc - in a way that NO software or OS or anything can deny the access. Is it possible and how can I do that?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to make it more "to the point". What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Was trying to remove AVG, but always got "Access Denied" -message, and got very frustrated.

Comment: Ah, that's not just Windows but possibly also AVG itself installing a custom driver which denies access to its own files. (Many antivirus apps call it "self-defense"...) That's something third-party software could achieve regardless of the OS, indeed it would be _easier_ to achieve on an OS that doesn't prevent tampering with the kernel, and malware/rootkits have done so in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way.

(In particular, because all file access goes through the OS – that's literally *the job* of an OS – it means the OS is always in position to deny a request it dosen't like.)

---

If you're just trying to recover your files, then a Linux liveCD will do the job because the default mode for its 'ntfs-3g' driver is to completely ignore NTFS file permissions.

If you're selecting an OS for your future PC, then Linux might also be suitable – not only its permission model is simpler, it is possible to have a blanket bypass using cap_dac_override, which the 'root' account has by default. Various BSDs and Solaris similarly have a 'root' account with unlimited access.

Unfortunately in your case, even though Windows *sort of* has a bypass mode in the form of SeBackupPrivilege, programs still have to opt in to use it whenever they open a file. Even if granted to the user, it still won't apply to all apps automatically.

---

But at some point, literally all requests go through the OS. So the only *guaranteed* way to make sure the OS won't deny some requests is to use an OS that doesn't have such any functionality to begin with.

So maybe also consider Windows 98 or Mac OS Classic or Amiga Workbench – they did not have any file protections at all. (Well, except for the 'read-only' bit.) Yes, they won't run any of your apps either, but they do make for a distraction-free environment.

Comment: how will Windows 9x run on a modern PC?

Comment: With difficulties. My point was that all modern operating systems have user accounts and file protections as a built-in feature, meaning there is always a possibility that they'll decide to deny you access.

Comment: OK, running Windows 9x/ME will remove User accounts and file protections, but they are too outdated, highly unsecure (Especially when connected to the internet) and lots of software will not run on them. So, as a workaround I was thinking of running Explorer as SYSTEM user. Will that help?

Comment: Do you know why they're highly unsecure? Because they don't have file protections. If you can easily change all files, malware can easily change all files too. Of course this doesn't prevent malware from getting _into_ the system – exploits are still exploits – but it does a lot regarding how far the malware can spread.

Comment: +1, I did get a Linux Mint to a USB and booted straight from there and could delete the files I wanted (everything AVG related). I'm not advanced enough to get linux working as I would want. Many of the programs I use are only for windows, but if I can find an equivalent for most of them I will change to linux right away.

Comment: Half of them probably would work on Wine (the Windows emulator for Windows). You can also dual-boot the machine with both OS installed at the same time – use one OS daily, reboot into the other OS when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from saying that Linux is better suited for this job than any modern Windows OS ...

First things first, you should know how to see hidden files. Inside cmd you can type `attrib -s -h` to see hidden and system files.

Next, you can use a tool like TakeOwnership which includes 2 commands: `takeown` and `icacls`.

You should have plenty of access to your files now, unless you're somehow restricted by the registry. You can give yourself permissions to registry keys with a tool like setACL.

If the files are being used by the OS, that's another story ...

Comment: +1, Close to one of my thoughts, if we put these in a Batch/PowerShell script, which will first list all logical drives, unhide all files, take ownership and change permissions recursively then the user will be able to browse throughout the PC without Access denied errors. But still running scripts like this is not recommended, becuase when  ownership of various system files have been taken and have been changed then it will be highly risky. So use these tools to take ownership of non-system and not so critical system files.

Comment: Files that are memory mapped, like all executable files, can always be renamed so they don't start next boot.